# DataGridView not positioned to the row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to set DataGridView  on the first row in the procedure scroll after a few scrolls. The DataGrid is redrawn, but it jumping again to the last line when the next key down is pressed. How can I change the behavior?

here is the code:

```
    private void Dgv_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement || e.Type == ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement)
        {
            Count++;
            if(Count == 3)
            {
                dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0; // after next keydown grid jumps to last row
                dgv.Rows[0].Cells[1].Selected = true;
                Count = 0;
                e.NewValue = 0;  // don't works
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex(v=vs.110).aspx), setting the `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property raises the scroll event so you are cascading calls to `Dgv_Scroll`. I don't say this often but I can't think of a reason why you would even want to do that.

Comment: thank you Crowcoder! This is an abstract simple test example. Such problems occur when I code paging data. The most obvious way is to load a new page when scrolling has reached the end of the current page. I see in the debugger that the assignment FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0 causes another scroll to my desired position (row=0). More scrolls no. But why then the key keydown not working correctly - is unclear.  The line number before assign FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex stored somewhere and there is a jump to this row when I press keydown.

Comment: If I move the slider scrollbar, everything works fine - the page refreshes and continues scrolling from the zero position